# Error placement, Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I have a problem with [select2](https://select2.github.io/) error placement when I save a form containing one or many select2.

Here is what I have: I have some Forms with some mandatory select2 inputs and they work fine showing the error with jQuery Validate but whatI want is the html to jump to the select2 with the error when I save the form. Currently the submit handler jumps just fine to any other element except the selectors.

Comment: Even though you've already posted an answer, you still need to make your question self-contained.  In other words, the question is unanswerable by anyone else without the relevant code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overwriting the invalid handler and call the id of the select2:

```js
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
        if($(validator.errorList[0].element).is(":visible"))
        {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
            }, 100);
        }
        else
        {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#s2id_" + $(validator.errorList[0].element).attr("id")).offset().top
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same jQuery validator, simply move the error

```
$("#your_id").change(function(e) {
   let id_error = `#${$(this).attr('id')}-error`
   if(!$(this).valid()) {
      $(id_error).detach().appendTo($('.select2-container').first())
   }
})
```